# How to remove some items by iterating over the array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to iterate through the array of object and remove some of them based on some condition.

I used splice for removing the items to preserve an orderly count of items.

Then each time the item removed I would decrease the count.

But for some reason it never works:

```
var arr=[{img:1},{img:2},{img:3},{img:4}];
for (var i=0, count= arr.length; i < count; ) {
    if ( this.arr[i].img==3 ) {
        this.arr.splice(i,1);
        count--;
    }else  i++
};
alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

​
...any ideas?

Comment: I think [`Array.filter`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_filter.htm) is what you need

Comment: I wonder if the `Array` thing would work in IE8. I will look into it.

Comment: BTW your method worked fine for me. The only problem was `this.arr` (didn't you mean just `arr`, since you declared it using `var`?)

Comment: @mgibsonbr I wonder what you've tried it on :D `this` refers to document and so `this.arr` is the same as `arr`.

Comment: oh, right! I tested it at jsfiddle, but the code was on `onLoad`. When I used `no wrap`, [it worked fine](http://jsfiddle.net/J7FSB/) (on most browsers, that is - Chrome, Firefox and Safari were ok, IE6 didn't have `splice` and couldn't figure out what were wrong with Opera...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looping backwards](http://jsfiddle.net/Xsqwg/) should do the trick. This avoids using counters and resetting the counter when removing an entry due to the "retreating" values.

```
var i;
for (i = arr.length; i--;) {
    if (arr[i].img === 3) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I would never thought of that. I think though it should be `arr.length-1` or it might also get bugged due to non-existing index

Comment: @Anonymous Actually it's fine. for-loops evaluate the second section (conditional section) before executing the block. So in an array of 4, `i` becomes 3 during the start of the block due to `i--` as the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler to loop through the array backwards, then you don't have to adjust the iterator:

```
var i = arr.length;
while ( i-- ) {

  if ( arr[i].img == 3 ) {
    arr.splice(i,1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this same difficulty before. My solution was to loop through the array and compose another array of elements to remove. loop through the list of elements to remove in reverse and remove them. This worked well for me.

Michael G.

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to `this.arr` instead of just `arr`.

Delete the two `this.` from the code, and it works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this loop, I haven't tested but should work.

```
var arr=[{img:1},{img:2},{img:3},{img:4}];
for (var i=arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if ( arr[i].img==3 ) {
        arr.splice(i,1);
    }
};
alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```